# Set the button text in a particular section of tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a table view (`tableview1`) which has a section header with a title and button in it.
The button has been assigned to the section header tag.

```
- (UIView *)mTableView:(TQMultistageTableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  //create uibutton 
    btnParentoptntype.tag=section;
    [btnParentoptntype addTarget:self action:@selector(btnParentClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

On clicking the button, it shows another `tableview2`(similar to the dropdown section). When a particular row is selected in this tableview2, the button(in tableview1) title should be updated with that text. I got the section index when a button is clicked

```
- (IBAction)btnParentClicked:(id)sender{
   
     selectedParentChoice=[sender tag];
}
```

How would I be able to set the button text of that particular section in tableview1 when a value from the dropdown table view(tableview2) is selected

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //How to set the button text of a particular section of tableview1
}
```

Comment: Using délégation  tb1 can declare a protocol method that tb2 could call. Tb1 can then update button selection .

Answer (score 0):

The sender in `btnParentClicked:(id)sender` is a button (eq. `btnParentClicked:(UIButton *)sender`), so it is possible to inject it into controller of tableview2 (or store in some tmp variable similarly to `selectedParentChoice`) and update title directly when needed.